# Find whether video is available or not using Selenium using C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, youtube, youtube-api, selenium-chromedriver

How can I find whether video is available or not using Selenium using C#?

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\chromedriver_win32");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v19-La3pTmU");

var result = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("reason style-scope ytd-player-error-message-renderer")).Text;
```

This is my code snippet to find whether youtube video is available or not. If not available I could access the text as "This video is unavailable." as shown below image, but I can't access this text using my code snippet.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the text **This video is unavailable.** you can use either of the following lines of code :

- *XPath* :

  ```
  var result = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='reason style-scope ytd-player-error-message-renderer']")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```
- *CssSelector* :

  ```
  var result = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.reason.style-scope.ytd-player-error-message-renderer")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```

Perhaps you may require to induce [WebDriverWait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_IWait_1.htm) in conjunction with [ExpectedConditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) as follows :

- *XPath* :

  ```
  wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
  var result = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//div[@class='reason style-scope ytd-player-error-message-renderer']"))).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```
- *CssSelector* :

  ```
  wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
  var result = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("div.reason.style-scope.ytd-player-error-message-renderer"))).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```